# java springboot+mongoDb difference between application.properties and .yaml

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, configuration

I'm trying to learn mongodb + springboot and I met issue like this:
When I'm using application.properties file to config the connection, then everything seems to be fine. config below:

```
spring.data.mongodb.username= root
spring.data.mongodb.password= example
spring.data.mongodb.database= database
spring.data.mongodb.port= 27017
spring.data.mongodb.host= localhost
```

When I'm making reference to profile with same config but in yaml, then authentication problem occurs. Config below:

application.properties body:

```
spring.profiles.active= mongodb.yaml
```

mongodb.yaml body:

```
spring:
 data:
  mongodb:
   authentication-database: admin
   port: 27017
   host: localhost
   username: root
   password: example
   database: database
```

It's not a problem with .yaml itself because if I change application.properties file to application.yaml file and copy config above then connection works.

So far I tried to play with yaml file, changed tabs to whitespace, quote the port number. etc.

I also tried to debug it and I noticed that when problem occurs, in one of method instead of reference to database name: "database" there is reference to "test" database so it looks like application is not even trying to read info provided in profile.

Do any of you know what is missing here to make it works?

error message below:

```
2022-06-14 14:41:35.642  INFO 13612 --- [           main] com.impaqgroup.training.Application      : Starting Application using Java 18.0.1.1 on ST002305 with PID 13612 (C:\Users\mkal1\IdeaProjects\course\target\classes started by mkal1 in C:\Users\mkal1\IdeaProjects\course)
2022-06-14 14:41:35.648  INFO 13612 --- [           main] com.impaqgroup.training.Application      : The following profiles are active: mongodb.yaml
2022-06-14 14:41:36.861  INFO 13612 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-06-14 14:41:37.141  INFO 13612 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 271 ms. Found 2 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2022-06-14 14:41:39.194  INFO 13612 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-06-14 14:41:39.259  INFO 13612 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-06-14 14:41:39.260  INFO 13612 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2022-06-14 14:41:39.653  INFO 13612 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-06-14 14:41:39.654  INFO 13612 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3906 ms
2022-06-14 14:41:40.163  INFO 13612 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2022-06-14 14:41:40.299  INFO 13612 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:115}] to localhost:27017
2022-06-14 14:41:40.299  INFO 13612 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:116}] to localhost:27017
2022-06-14 14:41:40.300  INFO 13612 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=13, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=59274900}
2022-06-14 14:41:41.636  INFO 13612 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-06-14 14:41:41.648  INFO 13612 --- [           main] com.impaqgroup.training.Application      : Started Application in 7.021 seconds (JVM running for 7.855)
2022-06-14 14:41:43.245  INFO 13612 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-06-14 14:41:43.246  INFO 13612 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-06-14 14:41:43.248  INFO 13612 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2022-06-14 14:41:43.473  INFO 13612 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:117}] to localhost:27017
2022-06-14 14:41:43.558 ERROR 13612 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'command find requires authentication' on server localhost:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'command find requires authentication' on server localhost:27017] with root cause

com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'command find requires authentication' on server localhost:27017
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.lambda$execute$1(FindOperation.java:670) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$2(OperationHelper.java:564) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:589) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$3(OperationHelper.java:563) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:589) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSourceAndConnection(OperationHelper.java:562) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.lambda$execute$2(FindOperation.java:661) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingSyncSupplier.get(RetryingSyncSupplier.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:692) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:86) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:191) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:135) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2830) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2558) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2540) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:849) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:444) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:154) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:61) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy65.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy65.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.impaqgroup.training.todo.service.TodoOperationsService.getAll(TodoOperationsService.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.impaqgroup.training.todo.controller.TodoRestController.getAll(TodoRestController.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Yeah it looks bad here. In code there's whitespace

Comment: Maybe you should set `spring.profiles.active= dev` and rename `mongodb.yaml` to `application-dev.yaml`. That should work. As far as I understand, `spring.profiles.active` is not for specifying an external file, it is for specifying the name of the active profile. And with the name of the active profile spring will look for the corresponding configuration file.

Comment: I just tried it, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jaimie your answer notched me to read more about profiles and I found my mistake. instead of using: 
`spring.profiles.active= dev`
I should use:
`spring.active.profile= dev`

Comment: I'm glad you found your mistake, but now you got me thinking: does `spring.active.profile` exist? I think it would probably work for you even if you didn't have that line. Can you try? Spring reads all `application-{profile}.yml` config files if it doesnt have an active profile so thats why probably it works for you, but I don't think `spring.active.profile` exists, at least I can't find it [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.0/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles).

Comment: I tried today with fresh mind. spring.active.profile does not exist and bcs of that it doesn't work, my bad. 
spring.profiles.active= dev works perfectly. 
So my problem was to name profile yaml in right way

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in profile name.

Instead of using:
mongodb.yaml
spring.profiles.active= mongodb.yaml

I should have used:
application-dev.yaml
spring.profiles.active= dev

Answer (score 0):

It seem you have problem in indentation:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      username: root
      database: database
      password: example
      port: '27017'
      host: localhost
```

You can use online tools for converting application.properties to application.yaml and vice versa

[Yaml to properties / Properties to Yaml converter](http://mageddo.com/tools/yaml-converter)

Comment: Structure of yaml is ok. If I use same code in application.yaml, without '''spring.profiles.active...''' step, it works. It looks weird here but there is whitespace in data line